# DefaultParser in Commons CLI doesn't behave like the deprecated parsers

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, apache-commons-cli

### Problem

I'm trying to parse some command line arguments in any order. Two of them are single-value and mandatory and the other one is an optional comma-separated list:

```
usage:
 -mo <value1,value2,...,valueN>
 -sm1 <value>
 -sm2 <value>
```

Using any of the old parsers (`BasicParser`, `PosixParser` and `GnuParser`) the code works fine but if I use `DefaultParser` instead, a `MissingOptionException` is thrown.

### Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Option;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Option singleMandatory1 = Option.builder("sm1")
                .argName("value")
                .hasArg()
                .required()
                .build();
        Option singleMandatory2 = Option.builder("sm2")
                .argName("value")
                .hasArg()
                .required()
                .build();
        Option multipleOptional = Option.builder("mo")
                .argName("value1,value2,...,valueN")
                .hasArgs()
                .valueSeparator(',')
                .build();

        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption(singleMandatory1);
        options.addOption(singleMandatory2);
        options.addOption(multipleOptional);

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        CommandLine line = parser.parse(options, args);

        for (Option o : line.getOptions()) {
            System.out.println(o.getOpt() + '\t'
                    + Arrays.toString(o.getValues()));
        }
    }
}
```

### Command line arguments

`-sm1 Alice -sm2 Bob -mo Charles,David` works

`-sm1 Alice -mo Charles,David -sm2 Bob` works only using the old (and now deprecated) parsers

Am I missing something? I'm using `commons-cli-1.4-SNAPSHOT`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug in `DefaultParser`.  Ultimately it boils down to this method:

```
/**
 * Tells if the token looks like a short option.
 * 
 * @param token
 */
private boolean isShortOption(String token)
{
    // short options (-S, -SV, -S=V, -SV1=V2, -S1S2)
    return token.startsWith("-") && token.length() >= 2 && 
           options.hasShortOption(token.substring(1, 2));
}
```

(Line broken to make it easier to read on SO).

Unfortunately this will always return `false` for "short options" that are more than a single character, because of the final clause `options.hasShortOption(token.substring(1, 2))`.  <strike>It will certainly fail on items 2, 3 and 4 in the comment immediately preceding the return statement, which leads me to believe it is a bug</strike>.  I may be misinterpreting the intention behind the comment, so please ignore previous statement.

A fix might look something like this:

```
/**
 * Tells if the token looks like a short option.
 *
 * @param token
 */
private boolean isShortOption(String token)
{
  // short options (-S, -SV, -S=V, -SV1=V2, -S1S2)
  // extended to handle short options of more than one character
  if (token.startsWith("-") && token.length() >= 2)
  {
    return options.hasShortOption(token.substring(1, 2)) ||
           options.hasShortOption(extractShortOption(token));
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * Extract option from token.  Assume the token starts with '-'.
 */
private String extractShortOption(String token)
{
    int index = token.indexOf('=');
    return (index == -1) ? token.substring(1) : token.substring(1, index);
}
```

Unfortunately there is no nice way to get this into `DefaultParser` as the methods are private, the calling methods are private (`isOption`, `isArgument` and `handleToken`) and `DefaultParser` relies on package local methods in `Options`.

The way I tested a fix was to copy/plaster `DefaultParser` into my local project, move into `org.apache.commons.cli` package and make the changes above.

---

As a dodgy work around for the specific case in the question, you could add a dummy short option `"s"`, which would trick `isShortOption(...)` into returning true for `sm1` and/or `sm2` options.  Something like this:

```
    Option singleMandatory1 = Option.builder("sm1")
            .argName("value")
            .hasArg()
            .required()
            .build();
    Option singleMandatory2 = Option.builder("sm2")
            .argName("value")
            .hasArg()
            .required()
            .build();
    Option multipleOptional = Option.builder("mo")
            .argName("value1,value2,...,valueN")
            .hasArgs()
            .valueSeparator(',')
            .build();
    Option dummyOptional = Option.builder("s")
            .build();

    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption(singleMandatory1);
    options.addOption(singleMandatory2);
    options.addOption(multipleOptional);
    options.addOption(dummyOptional);

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine line = parser.parse(options, args);
```

---

This issue on ASF JIRA appears to capture the issue, albeit with a slightly different trigger case: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLI-265

Answer (score 0):

With the "mo" option you're using the `hasArgs()` method instead of `hasArg()`. As a result in the latter case `-sm2` and `Bob` will be parsed as additional arguments for the "mo" option. When using `hasArg()` instead, the example works fine (you can still pass multiple values to the "mo" option)

Comment: Indeed. But there's a subtle difference. Replace the `for` block for `for (Option o: line.getOptions()) {    for (String s : o.getValues()) {        System.out.println(o.getOpt() + "\t" + s);}}`
to see it. ;-)

Comment: Ah, okay then the parser does not split the argument to multiple arguments at the commas. When looking at the Javadoc for the `valueSeparator` method of the `Builder`, it says it is actually not designed for the purpose of specifying multiple arguments but instead for specifying key-value arguments such as `-Dkey=value`.

I think you should perform the splitting with a separator yourself or use the method of supplying multiple values by specifying the `-mo` options multiple times on the command line like this: `-sm1 Alice -mo Charles -mo David -sm2 Bob`